# PHP form design help

Tags: php, html, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Robust, Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)
>   [Help coding an HTML Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508467/help-coding-an-html-form)

This is a mockup of design that I have in mind - https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgoeS.jpg

From each set of options, only 1 must be checked and depending on the combination of checked boxes the 'submit' button directs to a webpage.

The two features will be

Price(Please choose one)

1-99 100-249 250-499

Manufacturer(Please choose one)

A B C

[SUBMIT BUTTON]

The coding that I can understand which is definitely wrong is:

```
//search page
...
<form action='search.php' method='post'>
<input type=radio name=product value='a'>A?</input>
<input type=radio name=product value='b'>B?</input>
<input type=radio name=product value='c'>C?</input>
<br>
<input type=radio name=price value='5'>5-10?</input>
<input type=radio name=price value='10'>11-15?</input>
<input type=radio name=price value='other'>15+?</input>
... </form>
```

And in search.php, something like ...

```
<?php
$product = $_POST("product");
$price = $_POST("price");
...
if (($product == "A") && ($price == "5")) {
 Location("a-5-10.html"); // Products matching A, price 5-10 etc
elseif (($product == "B") && ($price == "5")) {
 Location("b-5-10.html"); //Products matching b, price 5-10 etc
....
endif
?>
```

EDIT as per OP's comments,
the request is not being redirected to "b-5-10.html" or "a-5-10.html" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` is an array, not a function, you want `$_POST['product'];`

```
$product = $_POST["product"]; //note [ and ] instead of ( and )
$price = $_POST["price"];
```

Also `Location` is not a function that I am aware of as @erisco pointed out you need to use `header`

```
if (($product == "A") && ($price == "5")) {
  header("Location: a-5-10.html"); // Products matching A, price 5-10 etc
} //also note the closing brace
elseif (($product == "B") && ($price == "5")) 
{ 
  header("Location: b-5-10.html"); //Products matching b, price 5-10 etc
} //again, closing brace, not "endif"
```

Comment: THanks this really cleared a lot for me. For the search page itself, could you please tell me how would I code the submit button request?

Comment: you just need an <input type="submit" value="Search" /> in your form and that will add a "Search" button

Comment: Thanks! When I am putting in the following on search.php and click search, it is just showing me the code on search.php
`<?php
$product = $_POST["product"];
$price = $_POST["price"];

if (($product == "a") && ($price == "5")) {
  header("Location: a-5-10.html"); // Products matching A, price 5-10 etc
} //also note the closing brace
elseif (($product == "B") && ($price == "5")) 
{ 
  header("Location: b-5-10.html"); //Products matching b, price 5-10 etc
} //again, closing brace, not "endif"
?>`

Comment: This is how my search page looks like `
<form action='search.php' method='post'>
<input type=radio name=product value='a'>A?</input>
<input type=radio name=product value='b'>B?</input>
<input type=radio name=product value='c'>C?</input>
<br>
<input type=radio name=price value='5'>5-10?</input>
<input type=radio name=price value='10'>11-15?</input>
<input type=radio name=price value='other'>15+?</input>
<input type="submit" value="Search" />

</form>`

Comment: If it's showing your code you need to make sure php is installed and working correctly on your server